# Solving the Diophantine equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=txyz$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Solve in $\mathbb{Z}^4$ $$x^3+y^3+z^3=txyz$$
(*Ion Ionescu*, 1931)

This is the problem.

What I tried to do:

$t=3+k\Rightarrow$ $$(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz)=kxyz$$

For $k = 0$ we have infinite solutions. For $k\ne0$ I have no idea.

Please help, I am confused.

Comment: [Status of x^3+y^3+z^3=6xyz](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384565/status-of-x3y3z3-6xyz)

Answer (score -1):

A very nice and elementary solution is given in the article

[Solutions of $x^3+y^3+z^3=n\cdot xyz$](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj6m8XNyKz1AhXpg_0HHYseADoQFnoECAMQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatwbn.icm.edu.pl%2Fksiazki%2Faa%2Faa73%2Faa7331.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2TRlSxj4cn08LDpd4nquQH)

by Erik Dofs. It contains references and tables with special solutions for some $n$. For example, for $n=73$ we have
$$
89200900157319^3+ 2848691279889518^3+ 1391526622949983^3=n\cdot xyz
$$